# Migrating to .csproj SDK breaks import of dlls from nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package

Recently I tried to upgrade my .csproj files to SDK standard using [.net upgrade assistant](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant). Initially it seems to work and all my nuget dependencies came along for the ride.

However when I try to build my project (targeting `.net48`) the dlls from the nuget package are not included in the output directory. I've been looking for solutions around the web, but most of them seem to indicate that they should be present. The specific package I'm having problems with is `RavenDB.Database v2.5.25041`. It is part of a test suite that needs this specific version so I cannot unfortunately upgrade it. The tests also do not run and complain about missing assemblies unless the dlls are present in the output directory (testet by manually copying them).

Running a build on the project before the SDK-migration works fine and the output directory includes those dlls. Does anyone know why this work differently in the new version and how can I resolve it?

Edit:

This is the `.csproj` file after conversion:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Data.Services.Client" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.4.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="RavenDB.Database" Version="2.5.25041" />
    <PackageReference Include="RavenDB.Embedded" Version="2.5.25041" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Edit2:

The `.csproj` file before conversion (warning, big):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="..\..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.props" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.props')" />
  <Import Project="..\..\packages\JunitXml.TestLogger.2.1.81\build\net45\JUnitXml.TestLogger.props" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\JunitXml.TestLogger.2.1.81\build\net45\JUnitXml.TestLogger.props')" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{7A3590CE-A43F-4A69-B520-27402FDD9F87}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Sti.TestUtils</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Sti.TestUtils</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Data.Edm, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.Data.Edm.5.2.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Data.OData, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.Data.OData.5.2.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Data.OData.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager.1.8.0.0\lib\net35-full\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\WindowsAzure.Storage.2.0.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Raven.Abstractions, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=37f41c7f99471593, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\RavenDB.Client.2.5.25041\lib\net45\Raven.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Raven.Client.Embedded, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=37f41c7f99471593, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\RavenDB.Embedded.2.5.25041\lib\net45\Raven.Client.Embedded.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Raven.Client.Lightweight, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=37f41c7f99471593, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\RavenDB.Client.2.5.25041\lib\net45\Raven.Client.Lightweight.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Raven.Database, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=37f41c7f99471593, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\RavenDB.Database.2.5.25041\lib\net45\Raven.Database.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.Services.Client" />
    <Reference Include="System.Spatial, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Spatial.5.2.0\lib\net40\System.Spatial.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="app.config" />
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\JunitXml.TestLogger.2.1.81\build\net45\JUnitXml.TestLogger.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\JunitXml.TestLogger.2.1.81\build\net45\JUnitXml.TestLogger.props'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.props'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.targets'))" />
  </Target>
  <Import Project="..\..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.targets')" />
</Project>
```

Comment: how does the output folder look like ? it there more than one  (net48, and possibly other output folders)?

Comment: bin\debug\net48\* in the new project. In the old one files were placed directly in bin\debug\*

Comment: Are there more ouput folders in the new project? Im trying to think where the dependecies got placed

Comment: @Menahem Subfolders within the net48 and debug folders are identical down to the binary content (verified with winmerge). Only files in bin\debug\net48 and bin\debug differ between builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround for this specific case. Since the dlls are downloaded as part of the nuget package you can force dotnet to include them in the build output by adding the following to the .csproj file of the final assembly. Meaning the assembly that is actually built to an executable.

Add the package reference and set GeneratePathProperty to true.

```
<PackageReference Include="RavenDB.Database" Version="2.5.25041">
  <GeneratePathProperty>True</GeneratePathProperty>
</PackageReference>
```

Then reference the missing dlls using the generated path property.

```
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="Esent.Interop">
  <HintPath>$(PkgRavenDB_Database)\lib\net45\Esent.Interop.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ICSharpCode.NRefactory">
  <HintPath>$(PkgRavenDB_Database)\lib\net45\ICSharpCode.NRefactory.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp">
  <HintPath>$(PkgRavenDB_Database)\lib\net45\ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Lucene.Net">
  <HintPath>$(PkgRavenDB_Database)\lib\net45\Lucene.Net.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Lucene.Net.Contrib.Spatial.NTS">
  <HintPath>$(PkgRavenDB_Database)\lib\net45\Lucene.Net.Contrib.Spatial.NTS.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Spatial4n.Core.NTS">
  <HintPath>$(PkgRavenDB_Database)\lib\net45\Spatial4n.Core.NTS.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

This will point the build tools to the dlls regardless of where it saves downloaded nuget packages.
Read more about [GeneratePathProperty on msdocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#generatepathproperty)

Answer (score 1):

You are building a *library* project. It is normal for full output resolution of transitive packages not to happen when building a library, because until an *application* project exists, it doesn't know the full story. Some of your transitive packages might have different outputs for different platforms; the *application* chooses the target platform, not any of the libraries.

Add an *application* project (just a console exe would do) that *references* your library as a project-reference, and look at the output folder of *that*. If your test project isn't working: check that your test project is using a project or package reference to your library, and not a dll reference to your library's output.

If there are *specific things* that still don't work, check whether there are package available for some of the many omitted references in the translation that might not be needed for *build*, but might actually still be needed at runtime.

Comment: That makes sense though that must also mean there is a new way to handle this problem in SDK vs legacy .csproj since the old project was also classified as a library. The project using this one is a test suite without an output type which I guess would make it a library?

Comment: A colleague just tried to use the nuget package in a standalone console application. The DLLs are still not copied to output.

Comment: @Thomas which dlls are you missing? do they relate to some of the references that *aren't* now listed as packages?

Comment: The dlls in question are those from the `ravendb.database@2.5.25041` package. At the moment only `Raven.Database.dll` and `Raven.Abstractions.dll` are transferred. Thats 2/16 from the nuget package.

Comment: I'm not able to find any direct usings for Raven.Database in our code, but there are several referring to Raven.Abstractions.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#restore-packages, in particular:

> After a successful restore:
>
> - For projects that use <PackageReference>, the package is present in    the local global-packages folder, and the project
>   obj/project.assets.json file is recreated.
> - For projects that use    packages.config, the package appears in the project's packages    folder.
> - The project should now build successfully.

By switching to PackageReference, you've changed the behaviour of the restore to the more modern setup where packages are consumed from a global cache (typically `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages`)

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding me. I'm not talking about the nuget package itself, rather the dlls within it. In the old structure these were copied to the output directory on build. This does not happen after the upgrade.

Comment: Yes, I don't believe I've misunderstood you. 

That's exactly what this documentation is talking about - because you've swapped to `PackageReference` those dlls are no longer copied into your build output directory but instead are consumed direct from the global package cache.

On restore you will now get `obj/project.assets.json` generated (as documented in the link) which tells your projects where to find all its dependencies.

Comment: But the build itself is not the problem. It builds just fine. The problem occurs runtime. I cannot run tests because the dlls are not accessible. I "fixed" the problem by manually copying the dlls out to the bin folder, but that is not a viable solution. Also, when building using PackageReference 2 of the 16 dlls from the package ARE included in bin, yet only one of them is directly referenced with a `using` statement. This does not seem like consistent behaviour.

Comment: Regarding the nuget location. I don't really care where they are placed as long as my code can run. And right now it doesn't unless I manually copy these dlls into the bin directory. We found a workaround by manually referencing the dlls in .csproj using `GeneratePathProperty`, but that seems hacky. What is the point of automatic package management if the package manager cannot resolve dependencies? This makes me think there is some config missing form .csproj that should resolve this. In the old structure all dlls were automatically copied without issue.

Comment: The automatic package management works fine, but you've likely got something "old-style" in your test setup which is causing you some problems.

I'm afraid there isn't enough information here to tell you what that might be though. This answers your question of "why aren't my dlls in the output directory". Your focus now should be to work out why your tests expect those dlls locally (rather than working out how to make them available locally). I'd recommend opening a new question for that with more information about how you're trying to run your tests

Comment: I have no control over how the code in the nuget package actually loads their dlls. The exception occurs within their code and travels back to mine. I don't reference any of these directly. As I wrote in a comment we've also tried with a standard console application and the dlls are not included on build their either. This means that building actually does not create a working application which seems very weird. I would expect there to be some way for me to indicate that I want these dependencies to be included so that users would not have to install nuget packages locally to run my app.

Comment: "Your focus now should be to work out why your tests expect those dlls locally". MY code does nothing of the sort. It uses RavenDB.Database which IS included and anything beyond that is out of my control. I'd be perfectly happy for it to resolve dlls globally, from userprofile, locally or whatever it likes as long as it actually does it. The reason the question is worded that way is because the only way we got the underlying code to work is to actually bundle dlls (dependencies) with the application just like it did before.

Comment: This isn't some criticism of your code - you're migrating from one way of doing things to another, and something doesn't like it, it doesn't mean you've done anything wrong. What I'm saying is that the dll copying behaviour you're seeing is absolutely expected now, and should work. As such your best bet is not to try and replicate the old behaviour in the new system to fudge it, but to try and work out why it doesn't work. But it's your code, you can do what you like with this information

Comment: I appreciate your help and I don't see this as criticism. But I also don't understand how it can be expected behaviour for a clean console application to only include a subset of dlls from a nuget package when bundling. That would ensure that nobody would be able to package an application with all dependencies and that can't be right. The behaviour I'm seeing is that SOME of the dlls are included, but not all. If it works as you say no dlls should be included since "packages are consumed from a global cache".

Comment: You also keep asking about packages when I'm talking about dlls IN packages which is why I think we have a misunderstanding. The **packages** are loaded from a global cache just fine. That is not the issue. The issue is that it only includes 2 of the 16 dlls from it in the output directory. I'm trying to figure out why these dlls are treated differently than the others when they are clearly referenced by the core package dll at runtime.